How to run a dynamically created YAML file in GitHub Actions
I would like to write a workflow optimizer for GitHub actions to eliminate some short comings of GitHub Action workflows. Especially, jobs can't wait on a single job in a matrix. While such a feature is already requested by dozens of users, there is no attempt from GitHub trying to implement that behavior sooner or later.
As a basic foundation, I need to write an optimized YAML file by a (Python) script and hand it over to GHA for execution. (I already have a parsed graph with expanded matrix nodes and optimized edges.) In GitLab, such a YAML file could be loaded from an artifact. Is there any similar solution available for GitHub Actions? Can a dynamically created YAML string/file be executed as a (sub/trigger)-workflow?
I know about reusable workflows, but these require a static YAML file in the same or different repository. These reusable workflows accept parameters, but not any YAML file structure/content, so I could redefine any job, parameter, needs-rule or if-rule.
I also checked dynamic-uses, but this is for exchanging workflows, which again need to exist ahead. Mine would be generated at runtime.

How to workaround that missing feature:

Let a job wait on the full matrix. This causes a non optimal overall workflow runtime and bad parallel execution.
Move dependent jobs into the matrix as a nested job (reusable workflow) and use if rules to skip unwanted matrix combinations.
⇒ this creates lots of unused dummy/skipped jobs.

Short comings of GitHub Action workflows:

Jobs can't wait on individual jobs in a matrix.
Nested jobs are not displayed correctly.
Output parameters of matrix jobs can't be used individually.


My goal is to optimize the workflow for GHDL, which will start 70-80 jobs for building and testing GHDL for various operating systems, compiler and tool versions as well as different packaging formats.
